# How to use php SCANDIR function to show directory listing that can interacted (e.g. if video then click to play)?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have couple of html buttons in a .php page that are supposed to show files from directory containing .mp4/video files. I came across **SCANDIR** function which is working and shows the files in directory.
However, I need the listing to be interactive like click to play video (something like a href or *hyperlink*). Currently, the displayed list is just plain text.
I just need the listing to have a hyperlink to actual video files which I plan to play inside another html-div.

The git repo of code:https://github.com/psedha10/Craigs-Music-Player

```
//from index.php
<button class="button-left" onclick="showLatestHits()"> Latest Hits</button>

<p id="song_genre"></p>

function php_func_LatestHits()
    {
        $dir = 'music/Latest Hits';
        $files = scandir($dir);
        foreach ($files as $value) {
            if ('.' !== $value && '..' !== $value && '.DS_Store' !== $value) {
                echo "<br><br>" . $value;
            }
        }
    }

<script>
var result_LatestHits = "<?php php_func_LatestHits(); ?>"
</script>



//from index.js
function showLatestHits() {
    document.getElementById("song_genre").innerHTML = result_LatestHits;
}
```

Comment: `echo "<a href=\"$value\">Click to play</a>;"` would be the href hyperlink? Unclear what exactly isn't clear here. What you have above is a mix of PHP and Javascript though, this clearly isn't going to work as it is? Please update your question with the _actual code_.

Comment: I have added comment showing which codes are from .php and .js file. Currently the value generated by SCANDIR function of a directory is stored in the <p> tag by using “getElementbyID”. However, my problem is the directory listing is only strings. I hope that explains my problems clearly. Thank you for your idea of using href instead of storing in paragraph. I will give it a go.

Comment: It's just basic HTML generation right, whatever tags you need to make? You could also just `json_encode($files)` and generate your HTML in Javascript, that'd be the cleaner approach, rather than storing HTML in a JS variable.

Comment: `SCANDIR` is the directory to scan for `*.ini` files ...

Answer (score 0):

I have found myself somewhat of an answer for the moment. The given code generates a video file after clicking play button and a tile/filename. However, it doesnt use scandir. It uses opendir and readdir functions of PHP.

```
//HTML Button
<a class="button-left" href="index.php?5060=true"> 50's + 60's </a>

//PHP function 
<?php
    function php_func_5060()
        {
            $dir = 'music/Fifty Sixty';
            $videodir = opendir($dir);
            while (false !== ($filename = readdir($videodir))) {
                if ('.' !== $filename && '..' !== $filename && '.DS_Store' !== $filename) {
                    echo '<img src="' . $dir . "/" . $filename . '" width="100" height="100"> ';
                    echo '<a href="' . $dir . "/" . $filename . '" target="yt"> Play </a>';
                    echo "<li style='list-style-type: decimal'><a> $filename </a></li><br>";
                    echo '<br><br>';
                }
            }
        }


        if (isset($_GET['5060'])) {
            php_func_5060();
        }
    ?>

//HTML seperate div that loads video using iframe from above link
<div class="bottom-middle-block">
        <iframe name='yt' style="width: 100%; min-height: 100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div>
```

A few caveats are iframe needs to be clicked after clicking play separately i.e. autoplay needs to be added. And, the img src used to show thumbnail plays the whole video in itself without sound like a tiny GIF.i.e. static image needs some modification.